# How to get partial specialization working on "std::vector" of "anytype"?

Tags: c++, templates

Assume I have the snippet below. How can I get a specialization for "any type of std::vector" for `MyMethod`?

Below I introduce `typename U` but this does not compile.

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class MyClass {
  T data;
  int myMethod();
};

template<>
template<typename U>
int MyClass<std::vector<U> >::myMethod() {
  // impl for any type of vector
  return data.size();
}

template<typename T>
int MyClass<T>::myMethod() {
  // generic impl for the rest
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: When you say "does not compile" it might be helpful to include the error message you get.

Answer (score 3):

You can't partially specialize a member function which isn't a function template, but you could add a type trait:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
template <class T>
struct is_vector : std::false_type {};

template <class T, class A>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T, A>> : std::true_type {};

template <class T>
inline constexpr bool is_vector_v = is_vector<T>::value;
```

And then use *constexpr-if* inside your method:

```cpp
template <typename T>
int MyClass<T>::myMethod() {
    if constexpr (is_vector_v<T>) {
        // vector case
        return data.size();
    } else {
        // generic case
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing concepts. You're thinking of method specialization, but that only works on template methods, and you don't have a template method. you have a non-template method on a template class.  But C++ doesn't allow this.

There's two general solutions:

- Have one `myMethod` implementation that defers to a template non-member method, and make a specialization of that.
- Specialize the whole class. (You almost certainly don't want this one)

example:

```
#include <vector>

namespace MyClassImpl {
    template<class T> int size(const T&) {return 1;}
    template<class U> int size(const std::vector<U>& v) {return v.size();}
    // note this is a little dangerous because 
    // `std::vector<T>&` and `std::vector<T>&&` won't match, 
    // so you may want to add more work here
}

template<typename T>
class MyClass {
  T data;
  int myMethod() const {return MyClassImpl::size(data);}
};
```